# How to send html mail with Content-ID header using mutt in command line

Tags: bash, shell, email, mutt

I was trying to send a html mail with images. But I am not familiar with mail headers, how can I add a image tag using `cid`, i.e. attach an image and make it shown in the html content?

```
<img src="cid:x">
```

This is my testing command:

```sh
mutt -s "test" jason@example.com \
    -e "set content_type=text/html" \
    -a /path/to/image <<MAIL
<img src="cid:0">
MAIL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a new feature onging in neomutt project.
Currently there's no way to add `Content-ID` header for attachments.
See PR: https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/pull/2049.